# App Showdown: Universe dependency

Tags: application-development, packaging, mono

I'm currently in the process of packaging my submission for the Ubuntu App Showdown.
I read in the rules that the package may not have dependencies that are not in the Ubuntu repository. But what exactly does that mean?
May I upload a package that depends on another package in the Universe repository? And if so, how to I submit it to make the build-service happy?
And if this is not allowed, how should I go about this? Include the library directly in my package?

Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may include dependencies from any of the official Ubuntu repositories in archive.ubuntu.com, which include, amongst others, the *universe* repository.

So to answer the question, you can submit an app that depends on another package from *universe*. Quickly will generally take care of this for you when running the `quickly submitubuntu` or any other packaging command, but if you need to add the dependencies manually, you can also use the `quickly configure dependencies` command.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. However, I'm not using quickly. Do I need to specify Section: universe/games instead of just Section: games in debain/control? or is this information outdated?

Comment: You don't need to specify *universe* in *Section:*, you simply list the packages your app depends on on `debian/control`'s [Depends](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-binarydeps) section